# Virtual machine into ISO

Tags: iso, live-cd

Can i customize an ubuntu image with a new theme, background and programs etc... and then convert it into an iso so i will be able to install the same operating system on a physical computer? I was looking for an answer for the past 3 days and could not find one. I would like to be able to just install the iso on some computers without needing to go into each one and installing everything again on every machine.

Comment: Maybe this might help:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)